# Why would PHP deprecate mysqli_stmt __construct

Tags: php, mysqli

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.construct.php)

> mysqli_stmt::__construct ( mysqli $link [, string $query ] )

> Note:

> In general, you should use either mysqli_prepare() or mysqli_stmt_init() to create a mysqli_stmt object, rather than directly instantiating the object with new mysqli_stmt. This method (and the ability to directly instantiate mysqli_stmt objects) may be deprecated and removed in the future.

But why would they want to do that? Wouldn't that break inheritance (you couldn't extend mysqli_stmt)?

Comment: Yeah, I must admit that that is quite odd and ambiguous on their part.

Comment: Have a read through http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php - this seems to (could) be related to the `mysql_` api. One user contributed note states: *"If you use functions deprecated in mysql, then may not be impemented in mysqli. Those need to be reimplemented if required..."*.

Comment: Maybe to bring it in-line with PDO at some unspecified point in the future, since you don't instantiate PDOStatement objects either.

Comment: See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/apis-php-ref.mysqli.html where one of those references https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/apis-php-function.mysqli-enable-rpl-parse.html states: *"This function has been DEPRECATED and REMOVED as of PHP 5.3.0."* Which I feel should probably have been made part of an answer to this question rather than a comment along with the other one I left, since that also references deprecated `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: Therefore, this all really boils down to have gone through those references which IMHO would have most likely avoided the question.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for here? Could you not raise an issue on the PHP source project instead? At least then you'd get an authoritative answer

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no reason to do that. As of now you can still create an instance of the class and use it as you normally would. For example:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$stmt = new mysqli_stmt($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM movie');
$stmt->execute();
```

The above would work but is not recommended and here is why...

You need to understand that mysqli was a cheap drop-in replacement for the old `mysql_*` library. The core design principles were to make it support newer MySQL servers and bring the support for prepared statements into PHP. The development focused on these key areas and anything that was an extra feature was of lesser importance e.g. inheritance/polymorphism.

The constructor for `mysqli_stmt` was added a little later, but its development never really finished. There was just no real demand for it. People migrating old PHP 4 projects to PHP 5.1 were not yet thinking in the OOP way. The procedural style was still prevalent despite PHP folks encouraging OOP. Not to mention that prepared statements were still a novelty back then.

```
// Both examples work almost the same way, but...
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM movie');
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = new mysqli_stmt($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM movie');
$stmt->execute();
```

`mysqli_stmt::__construct()` still lacks error reporting as of PHP 8.0. I guess it is not too difficult to fix it, but you need someone who cares enough to actually finish it.

In the meantime, you really should be using PDO. PDO offers more functionality (it also lacks some but it's highly unlikely you would ever need mysqli specific functionality) and is easier to use than mysqli.